# How do deal with System.OutOfMemoryException when setting a parameter in a QueryDef?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, dao

I'm currently working on a project where I need to split my database in many smaller ones.
As part of my solution, I use many querys to export my data to new smaller DBs.
I use something like the following code:

```
    For Each tmpQuery In MasterDB.QueryDefs
        tmpQuery.Parameters!BranchID.Value = BranchID
        tmpLocalRecordset = tmpQuery.OpenRecordset(RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenForwardOnly)
        Do Until tmpLocalRecordset.EOF
            ''Copy my data
        Loop
    Next tmpQuery
```

But for reasons unknown for me, `tmpQuery.Parameters!BranchID.Value = Me.ID` throws a `System.OutOfMemoryException`, even with Visual Studio and Task Manager showing that my solution is using less than 100mb of ram.
Changing from DAO to ADO or ADO.NET aren't options for me, unfortunately.

Is there any way to circumvent this exception?

Comment: Circumvent running out of memory... uhm, *except* adding more memory? Seriously though, that exception is often encountered when getting into an endless loop.

Comment: As I never get even close to my physical ram limit, I really think it isn't a real out of memory exception.

Comment: But a endless loop... Maybe one Query is calling another and the another is calling the one? I will look into this. Thanks!

Comment: `I need to split my database in many smaller ones`  why is that exactly?

Comment: Just throwing out ideas, but do you need to do some resource clean-up?  e.g. `tmpLocalRecordset.Close()` and `tmpQuery.Close()` each time around the loop?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you translate that code to Access VBA and test it in an Access session?

Comment: @Plutonix I need to split my database as one of my managers (It's a summer job) said only one would break under load, so I made a system that splits the bigger database in smaller local ones, that sync overnight with a bigger central DB.

Comment: @Mark It happens on the first loop. It screams of low memory as soon as I input the value of the parameter. But thanks for remiding me to close my recordsets.

Comment: @HansUp I will try that tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion.